# How to use GDAL with Python to make a GeoTIFF file smaller?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdaldem

I have a GeoTIFF elevation DEM raster file with x & y dimensions of 32,412 each. I'd like to reduce the dimensions of the file x & y dimensions to 14,142 without cropping or losing any more elevation accuracy as possible. I'm processing the file downstream and the downstream program can only manage smaller files.

I've tried this code but it seems to be cropping.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import os

print('Resizing heightmap file if necessary...')

# Open the image
ds = gdal.Open("./geotif_source_files/heightmap.tiff")

# Get the width and height of the image
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize
print(width)
print(height)

# Check the dimensions
if width * height > 200000000:
    print('Resizing...')
# Calculate the target width and height
    target_pixels = 200000000
    aspect_ratio = width / height
    target_width = int(aspect_ratio * (target_pixels ** 0.5))
    target_height = int(target_pixels ** 0.5)

# Create the output image with 4 bands
    output_file = "./geotif_source_files/heightmap_resized.tiff"
    output_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff").Create(output_file, target_width, target_height, 4, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    output_ds.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
    output_ds.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())

# Set the options for the resampling
    resample_method = 'cubic'
    options = gdal.WarpOptions(resampleAlg = resample_method,dstNodata = 255)

# Perform the resampling
    gdal.Warp(output_ds, ds, options=options)
    output_ds = None
ds = None
```

Comment: Note: The large file was created by merging several smaller GeoTIFF files with GDAL.

Comment: Is the main goal to get a smaller file size? Have you tried any compression options? There are many, e.g. https://kokoalberti.com/articles/geotiff-compression-optimization-guide/

Comment: The main goal is reduced raster dimensions, not file storage size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to use [gdal.Translate](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Translate) and specify

- `width` & `height`,
- `widthPct` & `heightPct` or
- `xRes` & `yRes`

Along with your desired `resampleAlg`.

E.g:

```
inds = gdal.OpenEx(inpath)
outds = gdal.Translate(
    outpath, inds,
    widthPct=50, heightPct=50, 
    resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Cubic, 
    creationOptions=["compress=lzw"]
)
```

Comment: Using this code works well. Thank you!
    gdal.Translate(output_file,ds,width=target_width,height=target_height,resampleAlg='cubic')